# What type of encryption that used in this?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm new on Mobile Programming especially encryption, is anyone know what type of encryption that used in this code below?

```
static String encrypt(String text) throws Exception
    {
        String password = AppData.ENCRYPT_SERVER;
        final byte[] pass = password.getBytes(US_ASCII);
        final byte[] salt = (new SecureRandom()).generateSeed(8);
        final byte[] inBytes = text.getBytes(UTF_8);

        final byte[] passAndSalt = array_concat(pass, salt);
        byte[] hash = new byte[0];
        byte[] keyAndIv = new byte[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 && keyAndIv.length < 48; i++) {
            final byte[] hashData = array_concat(hash, passAndSalt);
            final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            hash = md.digest(hashData);
            keyAndIv = array_concat(keyAndIv, hash);
        }

        final byte[] keyValue = Arrays.copyOfRange(keyAndIv, 0, 32);
        final byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(keyAndIv, 32, 48);
        final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(inBytes);
        data = array_concat(array_concat(SALTED_MAGIC, salt), data);
        return Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Comment: It's AES in mode CBC and PKCS5Padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer to your question in this line:

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

---

### [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)

[Advanced Encryption Standard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4xNJsjtN6E) - this is your encryption.

---

### [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC))

Cipher block chaining - this is the cipher encryption mode.

---

### [PKCS5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS)

Public Key Cryptography Standards #5 - This is the padding applied.